# Can't pass theme changes to children nodes

Tags: godot, gdscript

In theory I should be able to change font, textures, etc. of any control node (buttons, panels, and others) if I place all of them under a unifying parent control node and add a unique theme to that parent. However, it doesn't really work for me. See the pic.

[image]

`Main` has the theme set in the Inspector. It has a new global font and changed textures for buttons and panels.
Green - font and texture got changed
Yellow - changed partially  (in case of Panel, the font is changed, but not the texture)
Red - no font changes
For now, I've got only two things to change: fonts and textures. And if textures 'mostly' work (I can't get Panel textures to change), font is more problematic.

So, basically buttons get changed in textures, but not panels. Only option buttons and panels get changed fonts, but not normal buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: About the texture, double check if it is for `Panel` or `PanelContainer`. About the font... Idk, I just tested on my end and it seems to work. Which version of Godot are you using? - Anyway, you could open the scene in the Theme panel using the "Add Preview" button, and then use the control picked (dropper icon) to select the controls that not getting the changes and configure them there.

Comment: @Theraot, you are right, I mistook `Panel` for `PanelContainer`... dummy me. I tried the Scene Preview and picked the problematic buttons, but - the font file is there, and the font size is set too. And one more strange thing is that I change some borders on the textures now, and these changes are not reflected now on the problematic buttons at all.

Comment: @Theraot, I am on Godot 4.0.2 stable

Comment: Testing on Godot 4.0.2 I see no issues... Can you make an share a project with just the necessary to reproduce the problem? I'm thinking you might be running into something worth reporting to https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues (an ongoing thing is that there are resources that do not emit their changed signal, it might be related to that) - By the way, Godot 4.0.3 was released with just fixes over Godot 4.0.2 (and there is a release candidate for Godot 4.0.4), I'd expect no problem updating to Godot 4.0.3. Although I don't see anything about themes in the changes.

Comment: @Theraot, thank you for your advice. I created an issue ticket on git (https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/79822). And I also tried to reproduce the bug from scratch on an empty scene, and it reoccured for me. I'll try to update Godot itself, though I'm not sure it'll help (it may be the signal thing you mentioned)

Comment: It appears you got an answer there. You might answer your own question here if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the similar problem in the future: if you are setting a global change for a theme and you want it to be visible in all affected elements, check if you have not accidentally set something specific for a specific element.

In other words, if a button has a set font, it will not use the default font you set for the theme.

In even otherier words, go to the Theme editor, chose the object you're editing, Fonts, and click the Delete button you see there (if it is there) to use the fonts you set as default for the whole theme.